# Can compile Scala programs but can't run them

Tags: scala, compilation

I am able to compile scala programs using scalac in terminal but I get the warning.

```
Charless-Macintosh:src Charles$ scalac hello.scala
Charless-Macintosh:src Charles$ scala HelloWorld
No such file or class on classpath: HelloWorld
```

Is this to do with `.profile` on scala. I'm pretty confused as to what is happening. Many thanks

Answer (score 30):

The current directory is typically not in the classpath by default. So you need to give explicitly:

```
$ scala -cp . HelloWorld
```

Comment: I guess that's a Mac-specific thing?  The classpath definitely does include the current directory under Linux.  Is there something different about the Mac-specific shell script?  (Does Java itself do it differently?)

Comment: It depends on your Java setup. I believe sometimes it contains it by default, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

From `> man scalac`:

> The default class path is the current directory. **Setting the CLASSPATH variable** or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, *so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings*.

When you have the `CLASSPATH` variable set, scala will not include the current directory in its search, *you must explicitly add it*. This is why `scala -cp . HelloWorld` works.

To verify, perform `echo CLASSPATH` and it should give some non-empty string. Check your .bashrc/.zshrc files for any `export CLASSPATH=...` and remove these lines.

Answer (score 0):

This was also happening to me but I think the better solution is to modify the `CLASSPATH` variable to include the current directory in addition to what you already had. e.g.

`export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH`

Now, you can simply use `scala HelloWorld` without that additional argument.