# How to include a scala package jar file in the classpath when execute scala class file

Tags: scala, classpath

I wrote a small scala sbt project, and used sbt package to package it into a xxx_2.11-1.0.jar file.  Then I wrote a small object that is using a class defined in my scala project.

When I compiled, it was ok:

```
scalac -cp xxx_2.11-1.0.jar TestCase1.scala
```

However, when I executed, it raised an error

```
scala -cp xxx_2.11-1.0.jar TestCase1

No such file or class on classpath: TestCase1
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can compile Scala programs but can't run them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998824/can-compile-scala-programs-but-cant-run-them)

Comment: I tried scala -cp .xxx_2.11-1.0.jar TestCase1, still not working

Comment: You need a colon: `-cp .:xxx_2.11-1.0.jar`. Or a `;` on Window.

Comment: Thank you very much, ; is the missing puzzle